# Custom target with injected services for NLog with .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I'm using NLog with `NLog.Extensions.Logging` for aps.net core support. I need to create a custom target and inject service into the target's constructor.
The following code never gets executed:

```
public MyTarget(IService service) {....}
```

as soon as I remove `IService` param, everything works.

How can I inject my service into custom target?

Answer (score 4):

Still not sure what is the right and proper way how to do that. For now implemented in a following way (not a good solution, but at least it works):

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ......
   services.AddScoped<MyCustomNlogTarget>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                    IHostingEnvironment env, 
                    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
                    IServiceProvider provider)
{
    var nlogProvider = ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance;
    ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance = type =>
    {
        try
        {
            return nlogProvider(type);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return provider.GetService(type);
    };

    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
    env.ConfigureNLog("NLog.config");
    .......
}
```

It tries to resolve the object using out of the box NLog provider (for default targets and layout renders), if it fails (when trying to resolve my target with `IService`), it resolves using asp.net core DI.