# NLog Custom Target fails in Azure .NET Core 2.1

Tags: azure, nlog, asp.net-core-2.1

I've been using NLog with .NET Core 2.0 and a custom target to write to Azure Blob storage successfully for a while.

I've now upgraded to .NET Core 2.1 and the deployed solution to an Azure Web App fails because, according to the Kudu Event Log, NLog cannot find the custom target defined in the NLog config file, **although it appears to work just fine locally**.

My host builder is as follows:

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUnityServiceProvider()
            .UseNLog()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

and my NLog target is defined in the startup class:

```
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        HostingEnvironment = env;

        NLogRegistry.Register(env, new ConfigurationAdapter(Configuration));
    }
```

The NLog Registry is just a wrapper for a solution based on [Custom target with injected services for NLog with .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377283/custom-target-with-injected-services-for-nlog-with-net-core)

i.e.

```
    public class NLogRegistry
{
    public static void Register(IHostingEnvironment env, IConfigurationAdapter configuration)
    {
        //Setup custom NLog Azure Blob logger with injected configuration
        Target.Register<AzureBlobStorageTarget>("AzureBlobStorage");

        var nlog = ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance;
        ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance = type =>
        {
            try
            {
                return nlog(type);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            return new AzureBlobStorageTarget(configuration);
        };

        env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
    }
}
```

What I think is happening is that there is some change of behavior to the .NET Core pipeline so that NLog is being invoked before the Startup method. As NLog is configured to "auto-discovery" nlog.config, it tries to set up before I've had chance to configure the target correctly.

If I rename the nlog.config file then the auto-discovery doesn't happen and NLog has to wait until I've run the ConfigureNLog method in my register class. Then, everything works fine.

Does anyone know what the correct place in the ASP.NET Core 2.1 pipeline invoked by Azure is to ensure that I can configure the NLog target correctly before NLog tries to autoconfigure itself?

Comment: NLog tries to configure itself as soon you create the first Logger-object (Also includes static Logger-objects on class initialization). Maybe some dependency-injection framework is triggering some static class initializers?

Comment: @RolfKristensen I guess that makes sense, I wonder what's changed in the .NET Core 2.1 pipeline to invoke this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of injecting `IConfiguration` in constructor to your AzureBlobStorageTarget, then you can now just use NLog Layout-Type for the AzureBlobStorageTarget-properties.

Then configure the Layout with `${configsetting}` introduced with NLog.Extension.Logging ver. 1.4.0:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer

Maybe also consider changing to this NLog-target instead:

https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage#blob-configuration

But if you insist on using custom target that relies on dependency injection of constructor parameters:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Dependency-injection-with-NLog